# Mediapipe cant be installed on raspberry pi zero 2w

Tags: python, pip, mediapipe, raspberry-pi-zero

I am building a project, and I need to use mediapipe, Im using Ubuntu Server on it, but when I install the mediapipe library I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/project/core.py", line 4, in <module>
    import AppManager
  File "/home/project/AppManager.py", line 10, in <module>
    import mediapipe as mp
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mediapipe/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from mediapipe.python import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mediapipe/python/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from mediapipe.python._framework_bindings import resource_util
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mediapipe.python._framework_bindings'
```

So IDK what to do, I attempted installing bazel with a tutorial, but its give an error when I compile that, so I dont know what to do... I need help

I have attempted installing with:

pip install mediapipe-rpi3 and pip install mediapipe-rpi4

And when I run my program, that's give that error, I researched and I found what my error will be because I have not installed bazel, so I attempted installing, with not luck, when I attempt to install my output folder gives me nothing...

IDK if bazel its necessary, because when I installed the mediapipe via pip, it installs... I am really confused and if there is not solution, I am going to  restructure my code

and Its my first time here, Hi

Comment: how do you install it? What error do you get when you compile? We can't see it and we can't read in your mind - so at this moment we can't help you.

Comment: Sorry its my first time here, and my english its too bad, but rn I have written more info

Comment: Unclear why you're trying to use "Rpi3" and "Rpi4" named packages when you say you're not using those devices

Comment: Its because there is not package for raspberry pi zero 2, and I think there is not problem

Comment: The Pi Zero has a different chip than the others. It could definitely be a problem.

Comment: Hmmm... Then there is no solution at the moment, I think... Thanks, so I will try with another form without mediapipe

Comment: pip3 install mediapipe-rpi3 and pip3 install mediapipe-rpi4

Answer (score 0):

I successfully installed mediapipe on rpi zero 2 w, but i'm using Debian 10 on it. Unluckily, i can only get ~6 fps max with its hand tracking solution.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello, how you have installed it, I was attempting to install it on Ubuntu Server, with not luck